# how to setup worklight on public http server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am building worklight project using eclipse environment when i run the project , i need to connect my tablet to local network then only i works for me for all the server updates and all.
I just want to move worklight server on http server which i can access using `http://publicurl/anyprject` which runs on apache. Now i want to work on eclipse but whenever i deploy the project it should deploy on public so that i can access it from anywhere.
Just tell me the process and what the thing i need to move on public server.

Comment: What is your Worklight version?

Comment: I am working on worklight version 6

Answer (score 0):

Since you've come here to ask a question, please also take a moment to write properly structured and coherent sentences in English. This will only benefit everyone and you will get a better answer, and faster too.

---

Try the following:

Instead of choosing `Build All and Deploy`, try choosing `Build for Remote Server`; there you should input the external (public) IP address of your machine. Next, run the generated project in your device. This should allow it to connect to the Worklight Server.

Note that both the Worklight Server (or rather, the machine that hosts it) and the device must be on the same network, in this case - connected to the public Internet.

---

Based on your comment, you can:

1. I would seriously try to open your own machine to public access
2. If not possible, I would try to move to develop on the Linux machine instead
3. If not possible, then you must install Worklight Server on the Linux machine and whenever you make changes to the project - deploy the updated .war, .wlapp and .adapter files to your installation on the Linux machine
4. Build the app with `Build for Remote Server` so that it will connect to the Linux machine instead of the local development machine

Step 3 above means you'll need to maintain 2 development environments, which is not so easy.

If you are during development, you should aspire for options 1 or 2; in other words, create a proper development environment. In Mobile, this requires public Internet access (usually).

Are you a stand alone developer, Business Partner or a Customer of IBM?

Comment: Thanks , but i am working on my local machine with eclipse setup so whatever project i build i can access it on my local network that i know. What I am asking I have one linux server that is publicly available i want project to be deploy there and development i can do on my local machine so that i can access it from anywhere. I think u got it.